# Can I create a folder on the launcher?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, interface

In the application section of the launcher, there are folders labeled `Utilities` and `Sundry.` When you click on the one labeled `Utilities,` a container opens up below it with its contents, which are just some system things like help, backups, and archiver. The one labeled `Sundry` has Adobe Flash Player settings. This is similar to Launchpad on a Mac.

I was wondering if it were possible to create my own folders with apps in them. I can't drag icons on top of others, nor can I find any real folders on my HDD that represent those in the launcher (Nothing in `/usr/share/applications`)

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.03 with GNOME 3.28.2

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell extension called [Appfolders Management](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/) to do this - it lets you simply right-click the icon and you see the options available, which allow you to add to a new or existing folder.

See: [How to install and manage Gnome shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) to help you :).